# Is it possible to block dynamic advertisement pop up in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, popup, popupwindow

For an interview ,I've received demo site :https://automationexercise.com/ to create an automation framework in Selenium for add to cart functionality. But on running the automation code , I'm getting a dynamic advertisement which I need to close manually to proceed with the code. Is it possible to block the advertisement using Selenium?

[Attached is the screenshot of advertisement pop up displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkLYZ.png)

I've tried adding the code to close the pop up when it is displaying , but I'm not sure what should be the condition here because the advertisement is showing sometimes , and also in different pages.

Comment: Load Any Ad Block extension in your selenium session, it will block the ads